What's this construction combining a group action with a pointwise group?
A symmetry of the $n$-dimensional cube $[-1,1]^n$ is a permutation of the $n$ coordinate axes and an optional reflection in each axis direction (applied before the permutation, say).
Generalizing this, let $\phi:H\times X\to X$ be a group action and $K$ another group, and define a new group $P(\phi, K)$ as follows:

Elements are pairs $(a,f)$ where $a\in H$ and $f:X\to K$.
The group operation is $(a,f)(b,g):=(ab, x\mapsto f(\phi(b,x))g(x))$.

The idea is that $(a,f)$ means "apply $f(x)$ in each slot $x\in X$, then permute the slots by applying $a$", so $(a,f)(b,g)$ means "on slot $x$, apply $g(x)$, then permute to slot $bx$, then apply $f(bx)$, then permute to slot $abx$".
Taking $\phi$ to be the usual action of $S_n$ on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $K=\{1,-1\}$, we recover the $n$-cube symmetry group.
Is there a name for this construction or another way to express it? Are there "natural occurrences" of it (e.g. as the automorphism group of a geometric or combinatorial object) with $|K|>2$ or with $H\ne S_X$?

This is called the (restricted) wreath product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product

The comment identifying this as a wreath product answered my questions. Thanks!
